# Firestore orderby desc startAt returning no results

Tags: javascript, firebase, pagination

I have a collection I would like to query the results from in database. I need to order by descending and would like to "skip" x records and retrieve x records each time. The current query I'm using, doesn't return any results despite the fact there are 24 items in the collection. Changing `startAt` returns results, but in wrong order.

```
   const snapshot = await db.collection('Conversation')
        .doc("c0mZfX1ZkfathIwwYkMX")
        .collection('results')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .startAt(10)
        .limit(10)
        .get()
```

Is there a way I can paginate the results and make this query return results without keeping a reference to the last retrieved snapshot?